# Update recently updated row by id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, prestashop

In my prestashop database I tried to update the default product attribute when there is `0` quantity for that one.  I check if `quantity` is `0` and then set `default_on` to `null`. Then I try to set another attribute `default_on` with the same `id_product` only if `quantity` is bigger than `0`.

I have 3 problems:

1. How to check that there is only 1 result for specific id_product? If there is only 1 i don't want to update default_on.
2. How to check that all results for specific id_product has quantity = 0? I don't want to update default_on in this case too.
3. How to make this for all table? Loop?

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE ps_product_attribute SET default_on = NULL, id_product = (SELECT @update_id := id_product)
WHERE `default_on` = 1 AND `quantity` = 0
LIMIT 1;

UPDATE ps_product_attribute SET default_on = 1
WHERE `id_product` = @update_id AND `quantity` > 0 AND `default_on` IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join that gets all the products with more than one result.

```
UPDATE ps_product_attribute AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id_product
    FROM ps_product_attribute
    GROUP BY id_product
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.id_product = t2.id_product
SET default_on = CASE
    WHEN default_on = 1 AND quantity = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN quantity > 0 AND default_on IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE default_on -- leave the rest unchanged
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much but new promblem came out. There can be many rows with same id_product but only one row with specific id can have default_on set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Now i try different way:
1. Set all default_on to null
2. Set default_on to 1 on first id_product_attribute from id_product group which has quantity > 0

Problem is: what to do with all the rest product where all attributes has 0 quantity?

```sql
UPDATE ps_product_attribute AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id_product_attribute) MinID
      FROM ps_product_attribute
    WHERE quantity > 0
      GROUP BY id_product
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.id_product_attribute = t2.MinID
SET default_on = 1
```